# Error on server - but not on Dev machine

Tags: java, casting, java-5

I'm working on string casting for the following case. This line works locally, but does not work in the testing server that we have. Both servers run on JDK 1.5 and Websphere 6.1.

```
for (Object objArr: comm){
            schedules.add((String)objArr); //Error at this line
        }
```

---

Error that I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with java.lang.String
```

Is there a compiler setting in eclipse that I have to worry about?

Comment: maybe what is inside comm is not a string? It's the same of dev machine?

Comment: This is the result of a poor design in your application. I would try to fix this bug from its root instead trying to find a *solution* in another environment =\.

Comment: If that's the case then the  *data* is different on the server. The `Object` in `comm` *isn't* a `String`

Comment: Unfortunately, the database is same for both the environments. So, there is no way that the data type be different in both the cases, I agree @LuiggiMendoza about changing, we do have time constraints.

Comment: I think the reason is not in JDK 1.5. Can you print `objArr.class.getName()` to see really what class hi has?

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan it's `Object`, noted in the stacktrace.

Comment: Yes, I see, but author assumes that is `String` if he/she going to cast. So I'm going to think that the problem in "wrong" Strings.